# How to change size of title's text on Action Bar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, text-size

There is an `ActionBar` on each Android 4.0 application, and it got a title. I need to make this size less. But I don't understand how I can do it, because `ActionBar` doesn't provide public methods for it. **Remark:** I don't want to use custom views.

Comment: Nice, clean solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29266326/1617737

Answer (score 51):

Actually, you can do what you want to customize the ActionBar. It must be done through the Theme. You can do something like this :

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.Viadeo.Styled.YourTheme.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Aurélien! You should consider using sp inshead of dp for text size ;-)

Comment: Instead of hardcoding any size, you can consider inheriting from `parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"` instead. That will give you the standard larger text size, no matter what device you're on.

Comment: nice work i use this styling way for action bar and change the color and size and appearance of the title

Answer (score 23):

You could always do something like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<small>YOUR TITLE</small>"));
```

Comment: Worked for me, using Sherlock

Comment: Use html to set text is very useless wit hbad performance use style :)

Answer (score 7):

on my system, res/styles AppTheme has a note saying

```
<!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
```

and this is the style indicated in AndroidMainfest.xml.  I added

```
<item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
```

and it worked and I'd rather do this than a custom actionbar.

Answer (score 6):

I have followed this method to skip the creation of custom style:

1. Create a custom layout with required text size and
2. apply that to your action bar.

1) Create a layout file (titlebar.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here set your required textSize.

2) MainActivity.java

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); //bellow setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.titlebar);
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The text's size in Android ActionBar is **standard**.

*Since ICS, Android now develops a standard so that applications will (hopefully) follow the same UI guidelines and design principles.*

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

This is why you can't change it.

**However**, if you still want to do so, you could use a custom Theme or maybe implement ActionBar (a fork) and modify its sources: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar to get maximum control.

Comment: You could. But you shouldn't. Android's chrome is designed by UI professionals who study how a user interacts with a device, and optimize appearance and placement of all UI elements to facilitate good interaction. Modifying the chrome will make an app less usable and frustrate users.

Answer (score 0):

## You can use

```
subtitle:"exsample"
```

**XML**

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:subtitle="subTitle"
    app:title = "Title"
    android:tag="dff"/>
```

**JAVA**

```
getSupportActionBar.setSubtitle("Sub Title");
```

Comment: where is the solution?