# Android - ActionBar Size

Tags: android, eclipse, title

[image]

Whoa! It's huge! How do I change the size of it? I have made some search but only found how to change the font of the app title. Thanks a lot

Comment: By setting `android:textSize="16dp"`, for instance...

Comment: um thanks for answer but where should I set it? Tried it both on activity_main.xml and Manifest but didn't work

Comment: It seems to be a TextView, so use it in the TextView's properties.

Comment: So, here's a possible answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12899367/2649012](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12899367/2649012)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the system font settings.
If you set your textSize in `sp`s, your `TextView`s will respect system font size settings. If you need the size to be fixed, use `dp`s.

Comment: when it comes to add it on the activity_maim.xml I don't know in which particular field to add it. for example it containts relative layout, text view and edittext. When I add it on the first, it won't change and when I do on the rest two, it only change the size of them, not the title. thanks tho

Comment: @user3265784, oh, this seems like an ActionBar. Have you tried to launch your app on a real device? Btw, don't use Eclipse, use Android Studio :)

Comment: @agamov: why? he'll have a lot of problems, then.

Comment: yeah on a real device too, won't work. I'll see what I can do. thanks for help!