# Why can't I change toolbar textsize?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to change my toolbar text size and gravity. I create style in `styles.xml` like this:

```
<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:color">@color/colorHighlight</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

and I set `titleTextAppearance`, everything here looks perfect but it didn't worked. My custom toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#009688"
    android:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    app:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

What is wrong with my toolbar?

[my toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuHUa.png)

Comment: i searched a lot but couldnt figure out how to centre title using style. But you can do it programatically as shown in the first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443604/android-how-to-centered-title-int-toolbar-in-android

or create a custom toolbar layout as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font

Comment: also edit the question title to include the gravity problem. or maybe edit it out of the question body and ask a new question about the gravity error if above methods dont solve it

Comment: if you can get reference to the textview like by findview by id function, you can set layoutparam by code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try using

```
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
```

instead of

```
android:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
```

as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487312/how-to-change-the-toolbar-text-size)

For centering gravity refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443604/android-how-to-centered-title-int-toolbar-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I couldn't set gravity center. How can I see text in center and is it possible set text multiline ?

Comment: well just a wild guess but did you try 'app' instead of 'android' there too? if that doesnt fix it ill do some googling :)

Comment: shit that doesnt work sorry. i need a pic of how your toolbar looks at present. can you edit the question and add a pic?