# Title text size of Toolbar

Tags: android

I am using Toolbar on which i set title text.but for different screen i have define different title text size using style.
but the problem is when i run this on phone which screen is `mdpi` the title text size is OK but for the screen of `tablet mdpi` the Title is looking too small
this is my style

```
<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

this is toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
    android:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.SubTitle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

i have declared this style in all folder like `style.xml(mdpi)`,`style.xml(hdpi)`,`style.xml(xhdpi)` with diffrenttext size.
so please help me how to set text size of title so it look good on both phone and tablet

Comment: post your toolbar xml

Comment: add textview in your toolbar xml

Comment: Answer to the question on stackoverflow <br> <br>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487312/how-to-change-the-toolbar-text-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the toolbar text size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487312/how-to-change-the-toolbar-text-size)

Comment: You should check ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in all dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="myTextSize">xxxxxsp</dimen>
```

in values/style.xml

```
<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/myTextSize</item>
</style>
```