# Change color and size of the title in Toolbar- Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I am trying to change the title color and size of the toolbar but nothing happens. I search everywhere and nothing seems to work. I am using minsdk 19 api. Here is my code:

```
**activity.main.xml**

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

**style.xml**

<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
    <!--<item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryLightColor</item>-->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>

</style>
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


<style name="MyTitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryColor</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487312/how-to-change-the-toolbar-text-size). Add this to your Toolbar:

```
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
```

And create a style for it:

```
<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @LieForBananas-I want through a android:theme to change the title not from the app: prefix

Comment: @Nick sorry,  you didn't mention that. What I did is just add a style that has the textColor property and apply it directly to the `AppBarLayout` without redirecting it to `MyTitleTextStyle` like you did, and it changed the color of the text in the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. This will allow you to control `textsize`

Define `ActionBarTextAppearance` in `style.xml`

```
  <style name="ActionBarTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ec1212</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>
```

Then use in `main.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBarTextAppearance"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to achive tour goal is to  have Textview as title inside your Toolbar and then give your choice size and color

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        >
<Textview 
  android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_parent"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```