# How to add textsize for toolbar in the androidManifest inside an Activity?

Tags: android

Toolbar title size decreases when screen is change to landscape screen, for that I want to add a textsize in the AndroidManifest Activity. This is my code

```
<activity android:name=".Transportation"
            android:label="Transportation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TRANSPORTATION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".Transportation">
            </meta-data>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not change the toolbar text size in the manifest. you will need to add a style to the toolbar in the activity xml file.
check out this: [change toolbar text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487312/how-to-change-the-toolbar-text-size)