# Action Bar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to increase the font size of text used in action bar and to customize the layout_marginbottom for text?

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">90dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change size of title's text on Action Bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897071/how-to-change-size-of-titles-text-on-action-bar)

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom layout in action bar.

Try this link: http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/android-custom-actionbar/

Here you can find sample for how to implement custom layout in actionbar as well as you can set custom size of text over there.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done using theme

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.Viadeo.Styled.YourTheme.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```