# How to set PageTiltle FontFamily and Size in Xamarin forms Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a Android Apllication with Xamarin Forms. Page files are created in XAML. But Title Font properties changes are not available. My code is:

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.ContactsPage"
         Title="Home"
         BackgroundColor="#ff6600">
      <ContentPage.Content>
          <StackLayout Padding="110,190,100,80">
            <Button  BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Image="Button.png"/>
  <StackLayout Padding="25">
  <Label  Text="Button" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize="Small"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

How to change Title Fontstyle ?

Comment: Are you talking about the ActionBar/Toolbar Title?

Comment: [Refer page](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html?hl=ja)  these link named **Sheets**..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897071/how-to-change-size-of-titles-text-on-action-bar

Comment: Please if my answer helped you mark it as correct. Its a good stackoverflow practice. I appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

Start from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689641/how-to-change-font-family-of-label-in-xamarin-forms) then in the `ContentPage` add:

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Label VerticalOptions="Center" MaxLine="1" FontFamily="/*OUR FONT GOES HERE*/" Text="Our new title" />
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

or:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
   <Label VerticalOptions="Center" MaxLine="1" FontFamily="/*OUR FONT GOES HERE*/" Text="Our new title" />
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this in your `MainActivity.cs` below the line             `LoadApplication(new App());`

```
var spannableString = new SpannableString(SupportActionBar.Title);
spannableString.SetSpan(new TypefaceSpan("yourfont.ttf"), 0, spannableString.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
SupportActionBar.TitleFormatted = spannableString;
```

Comment: using Android.Text; and using Android.Text.Style;

Comment: Please if my answer helped you mark it as correct. Its a good stackoverflow practice. I appreciate.

Comment: @jzeferino, That didn't work for me. I used .ttf which works fine on the shared code and change the labels, entries, spans,... 
but when I use that code as instructed , It didn't work.

Comment: @Ali123 I changed the code to ttf. But Android supports otf.